# Enable anti-aliasing only for data series in QChart

Tags: qt, antialiasing

I'm using QCharts library to plot my data and I want to enable anti-aliasing for lines on chart. I found a way to do this and it is calling `QGraphicsView::setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)` on my `QChartView` object. When I use it, lines in the chart get anti-aliased, but square-shaped markers in the legend don't render as perfect squares.

Without `QPainter.Antialiasing`:

[image: Without QPainter.Antialiasing]

With `QPainter.Antialiasing`:

[image: With QPainter.Antialiasing]

Is there a way to enable anti-aliasing only for line series in `QChart` or `QChartView`?